# What to use instead of cliched exaggerated adjectives such as iconic?

Tags: word-choice, cliche

The English language expert at grammar.about.com advises on many occasions against using the word *iconic*, claiming it is cliched and will make you sound trivial, without saying what to use instead. Is it really technically wrong or bad to use this word (or such an overused exaggerated adjective in general, like *awesome* or *amazing*, as the expert suggests)? If yes, what should be used instead to avoid sounding trivial?

Example (taken from grammar.about.com):

Mr. Leopold is not turning 95 years old, but his iconic ice cream business is. . .

Comment: The point of advice like this is ***not*** to seek blanket, one-size-fits all substitutes, but tune and adjust your language to suit the specific situation. Words become cliched not due to any fault in themselves, but because they are overused as a cheap cop-out or default to free the writer from the the burden of original thought or creative wordsmithing.

Comment: Well, that's a sea change.

Comment: A _conic_ ice cream business might work.

Comment: Bravo @EdwinAshworth :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Dan Bron said, in comment. Why not try something that actually describes some characteristic of Mr. Leopold's business?  Such as,

> **Successful** *adjective*: 
>   having achieved popularity, profit, or distinction.
>   "a successful actor"
>   *synonyms*: prosperous
>
> Google.com [“**successful**"](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=successful+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=successful+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.0.9413...........0.EIPHQ1hCtvQ&gws_rd=ssl)